# Historical and philosophical reflexions about the concept of energy?

Tags: energy, resource-recommendations, history

Perhaps you know the books:

Concepts of Mass in Contemporary Physics and Philosophy

Concepts of Force: A Study in the Foundations of Dynamics

by Max Jammer, which discusses mass and force from a perspective which include much historical as well as epistemological, conceptual and axiomatic elements.

Are there any good books which discuss the energy concept in a similar way as Max Jammer discussed for example mass and force?

Comment: @David Zaslavsky Why is this question closed? I don't think it it off topic.

Comment: Book recommendation questions are generally not allowed, except for the ones that cover standard subjects of physics and are listed on the book recommendation thread. This is too specific for that, though. (This is our version of the SE-wide policy that recommendation questions aren't allowed.)

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime I found the following books:

- [Theobald: The Concept of Energy](http://books.google.de/books/about/The_concept_of_energy.html?id=YcPvAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y)
- R. Duit: Der Energiebegriff im Physikunterricht (in german; from an educational point of view)